# How to connect to Azure Databricks using Service Principal?

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, service-principal

I am trying to launch a cluster using Azure DataBricks using portal but I am getting an issue saying "Subnet provided does not have security group associated to it." 
But I want to connect it using the service Principal.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

While deploying Azure Databricks in your Virtual Network, **make sure to associate Network Security group (NSG) rules** that allows communication with the Azure Databricks control plane.

The virtual network must include two subnets dedicated to Azure Databricks:

- A private subnet with a configured network security group that allows
  cluster-internal communication
- A public subnet with a configured network security group that allows
  communication with the Azure Databricks control plane.

The following table displays the current network security group rules used by Azure Databricks. In order to ensure that your Azure Databricks service runs smoothly, Azure Databricks can change these rules at any time. This topic and table will be updated whenever such a modification occurs.

[image]

**Reference:**  [Deploy Azure Databricks in your Virtual Network (VNET Injection)](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html)

Hope this helps.